# Flask Mongolab error: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, foreman, mlab

I'm having this problem when I do "foreman start" on my Flask app.

```
(venv)Macbook-err:Example ld$ foreman start
14:01:50 web.1  | started with pid 1441
14:01:50 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
14:01:50 web.1  |   File "app.py", line 26, in <module>
14:01:50 web.1  |     connect('mydata', host=os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI'))
14:01:50 web.1  |   File "/Users/ld/Dropbox/Semester4/Example/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 160, in connect
14:01:50 web.1  |     register_connection(alias, db, **kwargs)
14:01:50 web.1  |   File "/Users/ld/Dropbox/Semester4/Example/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 54, in register_connection
14:01:50 web.1  |     if "://" in host:
14:01:50 web.1  | TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
14:01:50 web.1  | exited with code 1
14:01:50 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

and in my app.py (line 26) I have:

```
connect('mydata', host=os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI'))
app.logger.debug("Connecting to MongoLabs")
```

I did `heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI > .env` so .env file should be legit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you check what `MONGOLAB_URI` is echoing in your environment, sounds like its not as legit as you might think.

Comment: So I triple checked and it turns out that when I do `heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI > .env` the output is in the form of `MONGOLAB_URI: mong...` and it should be `MONGOLAB_URI=mongo....` Thanks for the suggestion. I feel silly.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI > .env` outputs in the form `MONGOLAB_URI: mong...` and it should be changed to `MONGOLAB_URI=mongo....`

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you use `heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI >> .env` with two arrows instead?  To append the output?

Re: https://github.com/johnschimmel/itp-dwd-flask-s3-upload